# Autocomplete values from other fields on form

Tags: jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'd like to pass values from other input fields on the form to an input with jquery autocomplete feature.  I try several ways but none of them work.  Here is an example of what I have so far:

html:

```
<input type="text" class="fieldname"/>
<input type="text" class="fieldname"/>
<input type="text" class="fieldname"/>
<input type="text" class="fieldname"/>
<input type="text" class="autofieldnames"/>
<input type="text" class="autofieldnames"/>
```

jquery:

```
$(".fieldname").each(function() {
  $(this).blur(function() {
    var fieldnames = $(".fieldname").map(function(){ return this.value; }).get();
    });
$(".autofieldnames").each(function() {
  $(this).autocomplete({ source: fieldnames });
  });
```

If I manually set the fieldnames array (i.e. fieldnames = ["aaa", "abc"];) autocomplete works but can't pass the values of from other fields into an array for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved.  FYI, this is what I come up with:

```
html:
<input type="text" class="fieldname"/>
<input type="text" class="fieldname"/>
<input type="text" class="fieldname"/>
<input type="text" class="fieldname"/>
<input type="text" onfocus="getfieldnames"/>
<input type="text" onfocus="getfieldnames"/>

jquery:
function getfieldnames(obj) {
  var fieldnames = $(".fieldname").map(function(){ return this.value; }).get();
  $(obj).autocomplete({ source: fieldnames });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `var` keyword to declare a variable, it becomes a local variable. That means that `fieldnames` is only visible for the function that defined it - and not to the one that tries to read it so drop the `var` keyword.

However, since `fieldnames` is a very generic name, you shouldn't make it a global variable(you should try to avoid with making global variables with non-generic names as well, but it's even more dangerous with generically named variables). Therefore you should declare it as a local variable - but in a scope that's visible to **all** the functions that need it.

Something like this:

```
$(function(){
        var fieldnames;
        $(".fieldname").each(function() {
                $(this).blur(function() {
                        fieldnames = $(".fieldname").map(function(){ return this.value; }).get();
                });
        });
        $(".autofieldnames").each(function() {
                $(this).autocomplete({ source: fieldnames });
        });
});
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but autocomplete still doesn't show.  I'm wondering if it's because the `autofieldnames` graps the `fieldnames` variable before it is defined.  Basically, I need a focus code on the `autofieldnames` to grap the `fieldnames` variable at that moment.  Not sure how to do this though.

Comment: Yea, that might be the problem. You can set the autocomplete's `source` after creating the autocomplete widget: take a look at the end of [this documentation section](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source). Just don't forget to create the widget itself once.